# Spring TestExecutionListeners and execution order

Tags: spring, testng, spring-test, spring-test-dbunit

I use `Spring` + `TestNg` + `Spring Test DBUnit`.

Right now I ran into the issue that Spring Test DBUnit `@DatabaseSetups` annotation is executed early than TestNG `@BeforeMethod` annotation.

I need to change this behavior to let methods annotated with TestNG `@BeforeMethod` to be executed first and only then methods with @DatabaseSetups.

Right now I have the following test class:

```
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
public abstract class BaseTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {


    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)
    public void setUp() {
        //do setup logic
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
    public void tearDown() {
        // do tearDown logic
    }

...
}
```

Is there any way with Spring `@TestExecutionListeners` to change the order of the processing? How to configure these classes in order to execute all `@BeforeMethod` first?

Comment: Are you sure about this? The method `com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner#beforeTestMethod()` which is responsible for working with the `@DatabaseSetups` annotation is being invoked from within `com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener#beforeTestMethod()` which is again being invoked only from within `org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager#beforeTestMethod()` which is invoked from within `org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests#springTestContextBeforeTestMethod()` which is a `@BeforeMethod`

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan thanks for your answer. I apologize, I missed the very crucial part of my code in the question. I have updated it now. The issue is that logic inside my custom `setUp/tearDown` methods is executed right after the logic defined by `DatabaseSetups`/`DatabaseSetup` annotations.How to synchronize them in order to be able to execute this logic in the proper order?